# Automapper - How to map object to list

Tags: automapper

ValueList model is

```
 public class ValueList
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public List<string> Values { get; set; }
 }
```

Value Model is >

```
public Value();

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public decimal Value { get; set; } }


          CreateMap<Value, ValuesList>()
              .ForMember( ???? )
```

I want >

```
ValueList [{ id, Value }, { id, Value }, { id, Value }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
    CreateMap<Value,ValuesList>.ConvertUsing<ValueConverter>()
```

then create:

```cs
    public class ValueConverter: ITypeConverter<Value,ValuesList>
    {
        public ValuesList Convert(Value source, ValuesList destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            // Create destination object here
            return destination;
        }
    }
```